# Cannot have internet on ADB emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I post this message because I've no more ideas to make it work...

First, 2 or 3 weeks ago, I had no problem to have internet network on my android emulator, but I don't know what changed.
I'm on a enterprise network and behin a proxy.

I created new virtual device and I tried the following tips :

1. I created a new APN in the device configuration, to use the proxy settings. I also tried to add proxy settings in the default one, it failed.
2. The mobile network is ON, I can't put wifi ON (it doesn't see any wireless network), and I'm not in airplane mode
3. I first launched the emulator via Android Studio, now I start via command line below

   ```
   emulator.exe -avd Nexus_9_API_23 -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -http-proxy http://<user>:<passwd>@<myProxy>:<myProxyPort> -verbose
   ```
4. I also tried a solution that consisted to disable my wifi adapter in windows (which I don't use, I'm connected via RJ45), but it didn't do anything
5. I checked the IP address of the ADB via  adb -e shell, and the linux ifconfig : the emulator has 10.0.2.15, but my windows is 10.156.55.30, so not the same network

And here I am...

If anyone could help me to find out what am I missing, it would be very helpful !

Thanks